# How can pass a props to a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying "hydrate" props from elements to child components that will render. The problem is that I can't figure out how I can do it with my configuration.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582087/how-to-pass-props-to-react-component-that-wrapped-in-variable), I tried to adapt it, but so far I'm getting errors (see bottom).

For a bit of background, I'm developing a Rails based application that uses React for the front end. So I don't use React router or such, it just "displays" the datas.

Here is how I set everything up:

**front.js (where everything gets rendered)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import extractActionName from './lib/extractActionName';
import {elementForActionName} from './lib/elementForActionName';
import 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap';

let actionName = extractActionName();
let value = "value";

let renderElement = function (Element, id) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Element value={value} />,
        document.getElementById(id)
    );
};

renderElement(elementForActionName[actionName], actionName);
```

**lib/elementForActionName.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Homeindex from '../home/home';
import Contact from '../home/contact';

// This files create an associative array with id React will be
// looking for as a key and the component as value

export const elementForActionName = {
    'index': <Homeindex />,
    'contact': <Contact/>,
};
```

**lib/extractActionName.js**

```
export default function extractActionName() {
  // The body contains classes such as "home index", so
  // I return the "action name" of my controller (home) to
  // front.js so I will render the good component

  return document.body.className.split(' ').pop();
}
```

**home/home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../layout/header';
import Footer from '../layout/footer';

export default class homeIndex extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <h1>Hello this will be the content of the landing page hello</h1>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

My problem is that I'd like to make an Ajax call in my "front.js" file, then transmit the received data (here, "value"). The error I'm getting is the following:

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object.

I'm lacking experience with React, how can I resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: oops, I forgot to edit that, no it doesn't, I was still working on trying to make it functional while writing my question, and I forgot to edit it

Comment: Are you sure your extractActionName() return something ?

Comment: Yes, so far, if I change `Element` to `element`  and I just render the variable as is without `value={value}` or the HTML tags, everything works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently returning the instance of a component:

```
export const elementForActionName = {
    'index': <Homeindex />, <--- here
    'contact': <Contact/>,
};
```

And then attempting to instantiate it again:

```
let renderElement = function (Element, id) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Element value={value} />,  // <--- here
        document.getElementById(id)
    );
};
```

Instead, just use the component class:

```
export const elementForActionName = {
    'index': Homeindex,
    'contact': Contact,
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this was way easier than I thought!!